# Different buttons in the same form

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have an asp form.it contains 3 menu item and save button under each menu[under each menu there are different fields]. I am doing validation using Ajax validators. My problem is after filling all mandatory fields for the first menu and on clicking  the button the page is not post backing.Because i have some other fields mandatory for another menu.How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Validation Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> Validation groups allow you to organize validation controls on a page
>   as a set. Each validation group can perform validation independently
>   from other validation groups on the page. You create a validation
>   group by setting the ValidationGroup property to the same name (a
>   string) for all the controls you want to group. You can assign any
>   name to a validation group, but you must use the same name for all
>   members of the group.

Basically you need to assign a validation group name for each set of controls you wish to validate and then assign the same validation group name to the submit button associated with that group.

From the above link:

```
<asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="RequiredFieldValidator2"
      controltovalidate="AgeTextBox"
      validationgroup="PersonalInfoGroup"
      errormessage="Enter your age."
      runat="Server">
</asp:requiredfieldvalidator>

<br /><br />

<!--When Button1 is clicked, only validation
    controls that are a part of PersonalInfoGroup
    are validated.-->
<asp:button id="Button1" 
      text="Validate" 
      causesvalidation="true"
      validationgroup="PersonalInfoGroup"
      runat="Server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ValidationGroup property of Validation controls of ASP.Net.

Please provide the group name to each group of controls.

Please refer this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Validation of fields will only be done when you mention the validation Group for the fields and in click event of the button. As you have other 2 menu's with mandatory fields with out any validation group name the button click event is trying to validate all the fields and not posting back. Give Validation Group names as A, B & C then try to validate...All the best